# Apache Beam: Flattening PCollection<List<Foo>> to PCollection<Foo>

Tags: java, apache-beam, flatten

Say we have some nested list:

```
["a", "b"]
["c", "d"]
```

And we can easily do the flap map in Stream API like this:

```java
Stream
        .of(List.of("a", "b"), List.of("c", "d"))
        .flatMap(List::stream)
        .forEach(System.out::println);
```

But doing it with "FlatMapElements", it was quite a mess:

```
Pipeline pipeline = Pipeline.create();
pipeline.apply(Create.of(List.of(List.of("a", "b"), List.of("c", "d"))))
        .apply(FlatMapElements.into(TypeDescriptor.of(String.class)).via(list -> list))
        .apply(ParDo.of(new SomeOutputFunction()));
```

Can we do anything else better with the flat map function?
A simple flatmap job should not be that complicated so I think I am missing something.
I cannot even replace `.via(list -> list)` to `.via(Function.identity())` due to the type inference problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

".apply(Flatten.iterables())"
it will convert "PCollection<List>" to "PCollection"

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Anyone knows how to do this in python?

Answer (score 1):

Please refer to the Apache Beam programming guide https://beam.apache.org/documentation/programming-guide/#flatten:

```
PCollectionList<String> collections = PCollectionList.of(pc1).and(pc2).and(pc3);

PCollection<String> merged = collections.apply(Flatten.<String>pCollections());
```

Comment: I have seen this before. This sample shows how to flatten "Multiple PCollection of String", but not "Single PCollection of List<String>". I don't know there is a way to convert it or not.

Comment: I assume you can apply the flattening twice in that case: 1st iteration List<List<String>> --> List<String>; 2nd iteration List<String> -> String.